# Set different ranges to Google Charts

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization

I have used [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/gauge) code to make 4 gauges. The gauge has a property to establish the maximum and minimum value of the gauge, for instance max:20 min:0. When I create the 4 gauges the all have the same maximum and minimum value.

My question is very simple, is it possible to set different maximum and minimum values to each gauge?

Here is the code I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>                                                          

<html>                                                                   
 <head>                                                                  
  <meta charset="utf-8">                                                 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,                     
initial-scale=1">                                                        
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">                                                                                     
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>                 
  <script type="text/javascript">                                        
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['gauge']});               
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawGauge);

    var gauge;
    var gaugedata;                                     
    var gaugeOptions = {min: 0, max: 20, yellowFrom: 200, yellowTo: 250, redFrom: 0, redTo: 4, greenFrom: 4 , greenTo:20 ,                   
minorTicks: 5,animation:{                                                
        duration: 400,                                                   
        startup: true,                                                   
        easing: 'inAndOut',},                                                                 
 }; 

    var gauge_text = 'Gauge';                                                                     
    function drawGauge() {  

      gaugeData = new google.visualization.DataTable();                 
      gaugeData.addColumn('number', '0');                              
      gaugeData.addColumn('number', '1');                              
      gaugeData.addColumn('number', '2');                              
      gaugeData.addColumn('number', '3');                              
      gaugeData.addRows(4);                                              
      gaugeData.setCell(0, 0, 12, gauge_text);                                        
      gaugeData.setCell(0, 1, 18, gauge_text);                                        
      gaugeData.setCell(0, 2, 6, gauge_text);                                        
      gaugeData.setCell(0, 3, 10, gauge_text);                                        

      gauge = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('gauge_div'));        
      gauge.draw(gaugeData, gaugeOptions);                               
    }


 </script>                                                              
 </head>                                                                 
 <body>                                                                  
  <div align="center" style="border:2px solid black; width:590px;height: 500px;">                                                         

  <div align="top" id="gauge_div" style="width:590px; height:400px;"></div>                                                                 
 </body>                                                                 
</html>
```

I am not very familiar with html, as this code is a secondary part of a Python project, so any idea or help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance;

Ander.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you'll need to draw a separate gauge chart for each set of min / max values

see following working snippet,
four different gauge charts are drawn, each with a different range...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['gauge']
}).then(function() {
  var gauge;
  var gaugedata;
  var gaugeOptions = {
    min: 0,
    max: 20,
    yellowFrom: 200,
    yellowTo: 250,
    redFrom: 0,
    redTo: 4,
    greenFrom: 4,
    greenTo: 20,
    minorTicks: 5,
    animation: {
      duration: 400,
      startup: true,
      easing: 'inAndOut',
    },
  };

  var gauge_text = 'Gauge';

  gaugeData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  gaugeData.addColumn('number', '0');
  gaugeData.addColumn('number', '1');
  gaugeData.addColumn('number', '2');
  gaugeData.addColumn('number', '3');
  gaugeData.addRows(1);
  gaugeData.setCell(0, 0, 12, gauge_text);
  gaugeData.setCell(0, 1, 18, gauge_text);
  gaugeData.setCell(0, 2, 6, gauge_text);
  gaugeData.setCell(0, 3, 10, gauge_text);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < gaugeData.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
    drawGauge(i);
  }
  
  var gaugeView;
  function drawGauge(index) { 
    gaugeView = new google.visualization.DataView(gaugeData);
    gaugeView.setColumns([index]);
    gauge = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('gauge_div_' + index));
    if (index > 0) {
      gaugeOptions.max = gaugeOptions.max + 20;
    }
    gauge.draw(gaugeView, gaugeOptions);
  }  
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.gauge {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 140px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="gauge" id="gauge_div_0"></div>
  <div class="gauge" id="gauge_div_1"></div>
  <div class="gauge" id="gauge_div_2"></div>
  <div class="gauge" id="gauge_div_3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It helps... Thank you.